# Is there keyboard shortcuts for changing slides in PowerPoint 2013 even when you're in the notes pane

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

When I go to lectures, I use the notes pane to comment each slide in the pre-distributed PowerPoint file. But to use PageUp and PageDown to change slide, I can't be in the notes pane. Therefore I have to use F6 and Shift+F6 every time I want to change slides. This slows down my note-taking significantly.

Is there any faster way to change slides?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on powerpoint 2010 for windows. Even in the notes pane, in the text editing portion, pgup and pgdn change pages for me no problem. What is your version?

Comment: 2013 on Windows.