# PowerPoint keyboard shortcut: How to navigate through slides but stay in notes pane

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

(Effectively the same question as [Is there keyboard shortcuts for changing slides in PowerPoint 2013 even when you're in the notes pane](https://superuser.com/questions/675446/is-there-keyboard-shortcuts-for-changing-slides-in-powerpoint-2013-even-when-you) but PowerPoint 365 in May 2022.)

When typing notes for a slide, I want to go to the next slide and stay in the notes pane. If you're in the slide pane, the page up/page down keys move through the slides. There doesn't seem to be a keyboard equivalent (e.g. CTRL-PGDN) if you're in the notes pane.

The closest sequence I can find is F6 to move from the notes pane to the slide pane, PGDN to get to the next slide, then SHIFT-F6 to move from the slide pane back to the notes pane. That's a pain.

If there's no native answer, it'll be AutoHotkey to the rescue, as usual.

PowerPoint / Microsoft 365 / Windows 10. Yes, I'm being lazy here, but I like my keyboard and don't like switching to the mouse unless it's the better way of doing things.

Comment: Nothing listed in [Use keyboard shortcuts to deliver PowerPoint presentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-deliver-powerpoint-presentations-1524ffce-bd2a-45f4-9a7f-f18b992b93a0)

Comment: Perhaps Alt+Q, defined as : "Read the next step (for example, the next slide, next animation, or end of slide show)". Question: Are you in presenter mode?

Comment: Another approach:  Go to Notes Page view. You can enter/edit text there, and the usual PageUp/PageDown keys let you move from slide to slide.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you, but did you possibly mean [Use keyboard shortcuts to create PowerPoint presentations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-create-powerpoint-presentations-ebb3d20e-dcd4-444f-a38e-bb5c5ed180f4)?

Comment: @harrymc I'm in Normal View, in the Notes Pane, writing my speaker notes, not in Presenter Mode. Apologies, but I don't understand the Alt-Q tip. (I'm only aware of that as the now-generic Office search box shortcut.)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg that might be the only native workaround.Thanks for the Notes View reminder. I'm really hoping to stay in Normal View because I frequently edit my slides and notes at the same time. Looks like it's going to be AutoHotkey after all.

Comment: Another (and probably way better) idea:  open your presentation, choose View | Window | New Window. Now you have two windows open on the same presentation. Set one to normal or even Slide view and the other to any preferred view for editing the notes.  Slide view = just the slide, no thumbnails etc. Ctrl + Shift click on the Normal view icon, bottom right of screen.